# Cypress - cy.intercept catching wrong url

Tags: javascript, cypress

i try to mock my API routes with `intercept` but i don't know why it's the wrong route which triggered (i'm on cypress@6.2.1)

i have two intercepts :

one for `/contacts` and second `/contacts/Contact-ARandomId`

`cy.intercept('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/contacts', {statusCode: 200, body: dataMultiple})`

`cy.intercept('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/contacts/Contact-ARandomId', {statusCode: 200, body: dataARandomId})`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref [Matching URL](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Matching-URL)

> You can provide a **substring** of the URL to match
>
> // will match any request that contains "users" substring, like
> // GET /users?_limit=3 and POST /users
>
> cy.intercept('users')

so `'http://localhost:5000/contacts'` matches because it is the first defined, and partial matching applies.

You could just reverse the order of the intercepts, set the more specific URL first (sort of like routes on a SPA).

Alternatively, take a look at [Set an alias dynamically](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/#set-an-alias-dynamically).

You can use javascript to refine the response

```js
cy.intercept('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/contacts', (req) => {

  const isContactById = req.url.split('/')  // split into parts
    .pop()                                  // take last part
    .startsWith('Contact-');                // check if has id prefix

  const bodyStub = isContactById ? dataARandomId : dataMultiple;
  req.reply(200, bodyStub);
})
```